# pymysql.err.InternalError: (1109, "Unknown table 'ALL_PLUGINS' in information_schema")

Tags: mysql

I have a Python Flask Server setup in an Ubuntu Machine  and a MySQL from XAMPP as backend for the same.

How ever when I try to access the database tables from my python program it shows as 
`pymysql.err.InternalError: (1109, "Unknown table 'ALL_PLUGINS' in information_schema")`

but i can access the database directly in MySQL admin page

the sample program I used to access the data.

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask import (Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, Response)
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'information_schema'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def insert_student():
    qry = "SELECT * FROM ALL_PLUGINS "
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(qry)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    conn.commit()
    return "Sucess"      

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
   app.debug = True
   app.run()
```

instead of normal running I ge the following 
[the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aNvR.png)

Comment: If you run the query in the mysql terminal client, does it work?  Is the table diaplyed if you run `SHOW TABLES;` in the `information_schema` database?

Comment: yes it does not only information_schema, no other tables can be accessed!!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not have an [all_plugins table in information schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html). The plugins table (well, view) is called [plugins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/plugins-table.html).

So, your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM PLUGINS
```

Based on the comment from @snakecharmerb:
Mariadb, on the other hand, does have [all_plugins](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/all-plugins-table-information-schema) table, which presumably is the cause of the confusion.

Comment: Mariadb, on the other hand, does have such a table https://mariadb.com/kb/en/all-plugins-table-information-schema/, which presumably is the cause of the confusion.

Comment: @Shadow  thank you guys... that was the trouble, the confusion between mariadb and mySQL